# ImportError: cannot import name 'SplineModel' from 'lmfit.models'

Tags: model, spline, lmfit

I am trying to use `SplineModel` to fit background noise as part of a Composite Model to fit a peak and a background using `lmfit` as per the documentation here:

[lmfit SplineModel example](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/documentation/builtinmodels_splinemodel.html)

However when trying to import the `SplineModel` package using:

```
from lmfit.models import SplineModel
```

I get the error raised above (`ImportError: cannot import name 'SplineModel' from 'lmfit.models'`) followed by the directory where the lmfit/models.py resides. I have tried to get the most recent `lmfit` from the `lmfit` GitHub advice page also, and tried to update according to `conda install -c gsecars lmfit` which did not work either.

I have also tried:

```
from lmfit.models import *
```

But this raises the error:  `NameError: name 'SplineModel' is not defined`. Does anyone know why I am getting the error? Is it some compatibility issue perhaps? For your information, I am using Python version 3.9 with Spyder as part of the Anaconda package.

Answer (score 0):

`SplineModel` was introduced in version 1.1.0, so your version of `lmfit` is likely out-of-date.  You'll want to update with `pip install --upgrade lmfit`.

FWIW, you could also use conda to install the lmfit package from conda-forge, but the result will not be different and conda will take much longer.